# Best directory for Gradle build resources (e.g. license header template)

Tags: gradle, build

I'm looking for the appropriate location to place resources that are used by the build, like a license header template file or a file with code formatter settings.

The `buildSrc` seems like the most appropiate place (e.g. `buildSrc/src/main/resources`), but I only found it mentioned in the context of [Build sources](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:build_sources).

Another option would be `src/build/resources`. Perhaps there are better locations I didn't consider.

What would be the most appropriate directory for these resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many gradle builds the convention of using $rootproject/gradle as folder for build resources has been established. you can have a config folder to store your license files / checkstyle configs etc. in there.